# Prevent server from going into a directory

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I have link called `http://server.local/documents/` I want to be able to echo  `documents/` in the index.php of `http://server.local` without going to the `documents/` directory. Is this possible using an .htaccess file? If so what do I write in it?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean other than `echo 'documents/';`

Comment: @scrowler When I type `http://server.local/documents/` the server redirects me to the `documents/` directory. I want to be able to do something like `echo "$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";` in the index.php of `http://server.local` without the server redirecting me to the `documents/` directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all of your requests to go to a single PHP page, something like [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/45552/how-do-i-make-all-urls-run-through-a-single-php-file) is likely to work for you:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```